# Facebook actionscript api logout not working on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, adobe

I have an adobe air application. I just added facebook features in it.

My problem is that user can login and do activities properly.

Following the code that i am using for logout :

protected function logout(callback:Function=null, appOrigin:String=null):void {
            this.logoutCallback = callback;

```
        //clears cookie for mobile.
        var params:Object = {};
        params.confirm = 1;
        params.next = appOrigin;
        params.access_token = accessToken;
        var req:FacebookRequest = new FacebookRequest();

        openRequests[req] = handleLogout;
        req.call("https://m.facebook.com/logout.php", "GET" , handleRequestLoad, params);

        var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(SO_NAME);
        so.clear();
        so.flush();

        session = null;
    }
```

i am passing "https://www.facebook.com/" as appOrigin

But the logout functionality is not working.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working?" We probably can't help you with just this information...

Answer (score 1):

The default logout functionality seems to not be properly clearing cookies via the FacebookMobile actionscript API.  The solution in [comment #33 here](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=297) worked for me, reproduced here.  Make sure to sub in your own APP_ID:

```
function logout(e:MouseEvent):void {
  FacebookMobile.logout(onLogout, "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=APP_ID&display=touch&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream&fbconnect=1");
}

function onLogout(result:Object):void
{
  trace("Perfect Log Out!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for an iOS mobile app. I just made a string, akin to the one in the previous answer and added the callback to `FacebookMobile.logout()`.

What's interesting is that this appears to log you out of the application, but the Access Token remains the same; at least for the short time I tested it, but it did force a new login each time nonetheless.